# Qu'est ce qu'une victime dans le domaine criminel ?

Tags: usage, vocabulaire, droit-et-justice

Dans le domaine criminel, lorsque l'on parle d'une *victime*, cela veut forcément dire qu'une personne est morte ou cela peut signifier qu'une personne est simplement blessée ?

Comment: Pour une étude très détaillée et sourcée : [V pour victime](http://vpourvictime.com/2012/02/01/recherche-dune-definition-juridique-de-la-victime/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Victime signifie « Personne qui subit personnellement et directement un préjudice physique, moral ou matériel, du fait d'une infraction pénale, par opposition à la personne qui le cause : l'auteur. » Un acte criminel n'est pas nécessairement un meurtre, il peut être une tentative de meurtre, par exemple.

Il existe d'ailleurs au Québec une [loi sur l'aide aux victimes d'actes criminels](http://www2.publicationsduquebec.gouv.qc.ca/dynamicSearch/telecharge.php?type=2&file=/A_13_2/A13_2.HTM), ce qui implique que certaines victimes ne sont pas forcément mortes.

Comment: Attention que, d'après [http://vpourvictime.com/2012/02/01/recherche-dune-definition-juridique-de-la-victime/](V pour victime) les proches et voisins de la victime principale peuvent aussi être considérés comme victimes. Une victime n'est donc plus seulement **la** personne qui subit _directement_...

Comment: Le lien précédent n'apparaît pas correctement, impossible de comprendre pourquoi. Bref, c'est celui donné par Evpok, V pour victime.

Comment: Oui, c'est la même chose avec le lien sur la loi sur l'aides aux victimes d'actes criminels, qui dit que "Sont également considérées comme des victimes ses proches et ses personnes à charge." On peut alors se tourner vers la définition d'acte criminel, qui est "le meurtre, les voies de faits graves, et les prises d’otage". On peut donc être victime d'un acte criminel et être encore vivant.

Comment: @Nathalie Laroche : Merci pour la réponse.

Answer (score 4):

La personne n'est pas forcément morte, non.

On peut être victime de harcèlement par exemple.
Ou avoir été blessé lors d'une altercation.

Comment: Même si on parle spécifiquement du domaine criminel ?

Comment: @Zistoloen Je dirais oui, même s'il est vrai que souvent la victime peut être morte. Ça dépend du contexte aussi.

Comment: Ok très bien, merci.

Comment: @Zistoloen - Beaucoup d'actes n'impliquant pas la mort sont criminels, comme le viol par exemple. En France, la distinction entre crime et délit est fait selon la lourdeur de la peine.